# Capistrano 3 - Cap Production Deploy Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, capistrano3

I am trying to run a production deploy. On server, I got this message:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 172.31.47.95: exit
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `exit'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SystemExit: exit
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `exit'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The deploy has failed with an error: `#<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 172.31.47.95: exit>`

However, when I try to run it on my local project folder, I get this error instead:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rvm1/capistrano3
/Users/administrator/Desktop/CitySpade/Capfile:22:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:24:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help? Thank you so much!

Comment: How are you running the command?

Comment: Ie., are you using bundle exec? Do you have a .ruby-version file? I notice you are running different ruby versions on the server and locally

Comment: looks like you're missing the `rvm1-capistrano3` gem. Did you add it to your `Gemfile`?